# Can I compile and execute programs from external programming language using Grails?

Tags: grails

I would like to write a program using C language or Java language.

and I want to give to this program as an input of a Grails program. After all ,How Can I compile those C program or Java program using Grails and get a compilation and execution test results?

Comment: dued it pretty mixed up of what you want ,,,be brief...

Comment: i would like to build an interface that could compile the programs that belong to other programming languages. the framework that i had chosen is GRAILS and language is GROOVY @danielad

Comment: you mean want to call a c complied library file function in groovy? that makes it simple :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you should take a look how to [Executing External Processes From Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy) and [Process Management](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management). So you can run any external command from grails application or you'd better integrate with ant or other build tool.